# Issues with SQL Server functions and triggers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, user-defined-functions

I have been working on this project by using "advanced" features of SQL Server and creating functions, triggers, but two of these are giving me serious issues.

I am supposed to create a function that includes one input parameter and returns a table. The function itself will return a summary of the individual costs of each insurance expense (base, spouse, etc.), a total of those expenses and the employees name given the number of dependents a given employee has- the user enters the number of dependents as an input parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnInsCosts
    (@NoDependants int)
--returns table datatype
RETURNS table
AS 
    --Set the Return to select the columns and aggregated columns from vwPayRoll as listed in exercise 3 of Module 12 --assignment sheet where Dependants is = to the input variable.
    RETURN (SELECT 
                EmpName, 
                SUM(BaseCost) AS TotBaseCost, SUM(SpouseIns) AS TotSpouseCost, 
                SUM(DepIns) AS TotDepCost, SUM(DentalCost) AS TotDentalCost, 
                SUM(BaseCost * SpouseIns * DepIns * DentalCost) AS TotInsCost
            FROM  
                vwPayroll
            WHERE 
                Dependants = @NoDependants
            GROUP BY 
                Dependants);

SELECT * FROM dbo.fnInsCosts(2);
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnInsCosts(0);-- Unfinished/error with select and EmpName?
```

Here is the error I get when I try to run the whole thing:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnInsCosts, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

And it says this when I run everything except for the part where I invoke it:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fnInsCosts, Line 10
>   Column 'vwPayroll.EmpName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

And here is the last one; I am creating a trigger and I need to create two table copies:

```
--Test for the existence of a fake table named TempEmpData. If it exists, drop it.
IF OBJECT ID('TempEmpData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TempEmpData;

--Test for the existence of a fake table named TempWork. If it exists, drop it.
IF OBJECT ID('TempWork') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TempWork;

--Select everything from EmpData into the appropriate fake table
SELECT * INTO TempEmpData FROM EmpData

--Select everything from Work into the appropriate fake table
SELECT * INTO TempWork FROM Work
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TempEmpDate_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE
ON TempEmpData
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    --(USE THIS CONDITIONAL STRUCTURE- substitute variable names where needed and remove the "--")
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted JOIN TempEmpData ON Deleted.EmpID = TempEmpData.EmpID)
             --the correct primary key)
    BEGIN;
        --Custom error message
        THROW 11, 'EmpID is in use; transaction cancelled!', 1;
        --rollback the transaction
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --Update the appropriate fake table
        CREATE TRIGGER TempEmpData_INSERT_UPDATE
        ON TempEmpData
        AS 
            --Set the appropriate column to the correct value
            --Where the correct primary key is in a subquery selecting that same key from the
            --system table that handles inserts
            UPDATE TempEmpData 
            SET BenPlanID = 0;

            DELETE TempEmpData
            WHERE EmpID = 41;

            INSERT TempEmpData
            VALUES ('Bill', 'Smith', '11/14/2014', 0, 0, 1, NULL, 2);

            SELECT * 
            FROM TempEmpData
            ORDER BY EmpID DESC
        END;
```

And here are the errors:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ID'.
>
> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ID'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TempEmpDate_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.

I would be extremely grateful for any insight.

Comment: The second error is because you're grouping by `Dependants` but you should by grouping by `EmpName`

Comment: And the function is `OBJECT_ID` not `OBJECT ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the "new" inline syntax to create a function, great!

The first error comes from the missing "GO" to separate the creation of your function from the call to it

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnInsCosts()
--You function code here

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.fnInsCosts(2);
```

The second error in your function has its reason - as stated by JamesZ already - in the wrong grouping column:

```
SELECT EmpName, 
       SUM(BaseCost) AS TotBaseCost, 
       SUM(SpouseIns) AS TotSpouseCost, 
       SUM(DepIns) AS TotDepCost, 
       SUM(DentalCost) AS TotDentalCost, 
       SUM(BaseCost * SpouseIns * DepIns * DentalCost) AS TotInsCost
FROM  vwPayroll
WHERE Dependants = @NoDependants
GROUP BY EmpName
```

You see, that the only column which has not got any aggregation function is the EmpName...

And the last one - again stated by JamesZ already is the missing underscore in the function's name `OBJECT ID`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempEmpData') IS NOT NULL
```

In your code T-SQL is searching for the meaning of "object" and for a function called "ID"... (The same with `IF OBJECT ID('TempWork') IS NOT NULL`)

And one last point: On SO it is highly advised to create one question per issue. This question should've been at least parted in two separate questions. Just think of future readers searching for similar problems...

#### EDIT Ups, there was even one more...

Your last error message points to some code where I do not understand what you really want to achieve...  Are you creating a trigger from within the trigger? Might be, the `MERGE` statement was the better approach for your needs anyway...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry about that; I assumed I would be taking up too much space if I were to split up the questions, but it makes sense.

Comment: As for my last query, this is the summary: 

"The purpose of this trigger will be to prevent deletions of employees from the TempEmpData table if they have a corresponding record in the TempWork table and to make sure new employees are not inadvertently given an insurance plan (ID 0 is a 90 day probation period listing)."

Comment: @Pau808 It is not possible to use a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement within other code. This must be the first statement in a batch.... I'd suggest to start a new question, where you describe your problem and show what you've tried so far (with some sample data or a [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com). Place a link to this question somewhere in your quesion which will connect these questions. Happy Coding!

Comment: @Pau808 You might read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx): middle of the page "Trigger limitations"

Comment: @Pau808 May I ask, why you removed the acceptance check again? Are there any open problems with my answer?

Comment: My mistake, I have a bit of a trigger finger. Thank you very much for the help, I will create a new question for that trigger, thanks again..